# JAVA help of getting sum of inputs

Tags: java, loops, input, while-loop

I'm trying to write a JAVA code which keeps accepting integers until it reaches a specific number, so after that, the user has to input 0s for the remaining inputs in order to keep the sum of inputs <= condition

EXAMPLE: if i have 5 cups of coffees and 5 shots available, the user enters 3 shots for the first cup of coffee, and then 2 shots for the second cup. So now 3+2 = 5 shots which is the number of coffee shots available, so for the next 3 coffee cups the user SHOULD enter 0s to proceed, otherwise it keeps looping.

This is how my code looks like:

```
int add = 0;
int[] numberOfCoffeeShots = new int[coffeeCupsAvailable]; //input number of shots for every coffee cup
int i; //declares i

 for (i = 0; i < coffeCupsWanted; i++) { //iterate over a range of values.
 System.out.print("How many coffee shots in cup " + (i + 1) + "? ");
 numberOfCoffeeShots[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
 add += (numberOfCoffeeShots[i]); //adding the number of shots in each cup

while (numberOfCoffeeShots[i] < 0) {
System.out.println("Does not compute. Try again.");
System.out.print("How many coffee shots in cup " + (i + 1) + "? ");
numberOfCoffeeShots[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
}    

 while (numberOfCoffeeShots[i] > coffeeShotsAvailable) {
 System.out.println("There are only " + coffeeShotsAvailable + " coffee shots left. Try again.");
  System.out.print("How many coffee shots in cup " + (i + 1) + "? ");
  numberOfCoffeeShots[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
 }
```

I still need the while loop for the sum of inputs > coffeeShotsAvailable

Any help please about this idea ?? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAVA sum of inputs Greater Than a specific condition unaccepted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36479536/java-sum-of-inputs-greater-than-a-specific-condition-unaccepted)

Comment: i know am trying to delete the old 1 sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution. Beneath this code is a complete walkthrough the program and why it works.

```
public class CoffeeAndShots{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numberOfCoffees = 5;
        int numberOfShots = 5;
        int[] coffeeShots = new int[numberOfCoffees];

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfCoffees; i++)
            coffeeShots[i] = -1;

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfCoffees; i++){
            int input;
            while(coffeeShots[i] < 0){
                System.out.println("How many shots for coffee cup " + (i + 1) + "?");
                input = keyboard.nextInt();
                if(input > numberOfShots)
                    System.out.println("You don't have that many shots");
                else{
                    coffeeShots[i] = input;
                    numberOfShots = numberOfShots - input;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfCoffees; i++)
            System.out.println(coffeeShots[i] + " shots for coffee cup " + (i + 1));
    }


}
```

`coffeeShots` is an integer array initialized with a number of terms equal to the number of coffee cups we're working with. In the `for` loop immediately after, each term in that array is set to `-1`. This is because later in the program there is a possibility that the user does not allocate any shots for the specific coffee cup. In the next `for` loop, we go through each term in the array of coffee cups. For each cup, we will ask the user how many shots they want for that cup until a value greater than or equal to 0 is accepted. In accepting values, we need to make sure that the number of shots specified is actually available. If it is, we set the number of shots for that cup to the inputted value, then deduct our total shots by the number we allocated. When it's all said and done, we print the entire array.